# failed to merge manifest

Tags: java, android, xml

> an activity cannot be launched and the application is getting crashed
>
> i tried to add some dependencies but it is failing to merge the
>   manifest

```
   package com.example.penaliz;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.vision.CameraSource;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.Detector;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.text.TextBlock;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.text.TextRecognizer;

import java.io.IOException;


public class camActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SurfaceView cameraView;

    String s1;
    TextView textView;
    CameraSource cameraSource;
    final int RequestCameraPermissionID = 1001;

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case RequestCameraPermissionID: {
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        return;
                    }
                    try {
                        cameraSource.start(cameraView.getHolder());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cam);

        cameraView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);

        TextRecognizer textRecognizer = new TextRecognizer.Builder(getApplicationContext()).build();
        if (!textRecognizer.isOperational()) {
            Log.w("MainActivity", "Detector dependencies are not yet available");
        } else {

            cameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(getApplicationContext(), textRecognizer)
                    .setFacing(CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_BACK)
                    .setRequestedPreviewSize(1280, 1024)
                    .setRequestedFps(2.0f)
                    .setAutoFocusEnabled(true)
                    .build();
            cameraView.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {

                    try {
                        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(camActivity.this,
                                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                                    RequestCameraPermissionID);
                            return;
                        }
                        cameraSource.start(cameraView.getHolder());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
                    cameraSource.stop();
                }
            });

            textRecognizer.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<TextBlock>() {
                @Override
                public void release() {

                }

                @Override
                public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<TextBlock> detections) {

                    final SparseArray<TextBlock> items = detections.getDetectedItems();
                    if(items.size() != 0)
                    {
                        textView.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                                for(int i =0;i<items.size();++i)
                                {
                                    TextBlock item = items.valueAt(i);
                                    stringBuilder.append(item.getValue());
                                    stringBuilder.append("\n");
                                }
                                textView.setText(stringBuilder.toString());

                            }
                        });

                        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
                        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                s1=textView.getText().toString();

                                Intent i = new Intent(camActivity.this,Affance.class);
                                i.putExtra("message",s1);
                                startActivity(i);
                            }
                        });

                    }
                }
            });
        }


    }
}
```

> it is showing the below log i cant understand it
>   do i have to add some dependencies to make this work,
>   i can run the app on android device, but when i try to launch the
>   activityit is getting crashed

```
   '''`E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.example.penaliz, PID: 31333
        java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zztl;
            at com.google.android.gms.vision.internal.client.zza.zzcls(Unknown Source:13)
            at com.google.android.gms.vision.text.internal.client.zzg.<init>(Unknown Source:7)
            at com.google.android.gms.vision.text.TextRecognizer$Builder.build(Unknown Source:6)
            at com.example.penaliz.camActivity.onCreate(camActivity.java:63)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2926)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3081)
            at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
            at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
            at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1838)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6715)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:911)
         Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.internal.zztl" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.penaliz-Y6sjCxlQmwAdFU1Jik2q8A==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.penaliz-Y6sjCxlQmwAdFU1Jik2q8A==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.penaliz-Y6sjCxlQmwAdFU1Jik2q8A==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.penaliz-Y6sjCxlQmwAdFU1Jik2q8A==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.penaliz-Y6sjCxlQmwAdFU1Jik2q8A==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.penaliz-Y6sjCxlQmwAdFU1Jik2q8A==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.penaliz-Y6sjCxlQmwAdFU1Jik2q8A==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.penaliz-Y6sjCxlQmwAdFU1Jik2q8A==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.penaliz-Y6sjCxlQmwAdFU1Jik2q8A==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.penaliz-Y6sjCxlQmwAdFU1Jik2q8A==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.penaliz-Y6sjCxlQmwAdFU1Jik2q8A==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.penaliz-Y6sjCxlQmwAdFU1Jik2q8A==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.penaliz-Y6sjCxlQmwAdFU1Jik2q8A==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.penaliz-Y6sjCxlQmwAdFU1Jik2q8A==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64]]
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
            at com.google.android.gms.vision.internal.client.zza.zzcls(Unknown Source:13) 
            at com.google.android.gms.vision.text.internal.client.zzg.<init>(Unknown Source:7) 
            at com.google.android.gms.vision.text.TextRecognizer$Builder.build(Unknown Source:6) 
            at com.example.penaliz.camActivity.onCreate(camActivity.java:63) 
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136) 
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127) 
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2926) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3081) 
            at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
            at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
            at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1838) 
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6715) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:911) 
            Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location /data/app/com.example.penaliz-Y6sjCxlQmwAdFU1Jik2q8A==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk
            at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
            at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:354)
            at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:101)
            at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:75)
            at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:394)
            at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:354)
            at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:164)
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:74)
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
            at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
    E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:73)
            at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:88)
            at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:74)
            at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:40)
            at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:727)
            at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:810)
            at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1032)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2346)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5789)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:208)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1680)
                    ... 6 more`
```

> what could i correct to make that activity too work
>   this is the dependencies file

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.penaliz"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true;
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.6'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.5'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:9.8.0'





}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

> and this is the manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.penaliz">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/sc"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/roundlogo"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        >

        <activity android:name=".SplashScreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ResetPassword" />
        <activity android:name=".camActivity">



        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".FineList" />
        <activity android:name=".Email_Send" />
        <activity android:name=".Affance" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: in your build.gradle file use the same version for all of your `firebase` dependencies. it may solve the problem

Comment: Can u describe it please

Comment: Open your manifest file. You will get 2 options below Text & Merged Manifest. Click on Merged Manifest and try to locate the error there on the right hand side. If you haven't tried this yet.

Answer (score 0):

That error is probably because these dependencies have different version numbers:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.6'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.5'
```

so try to change them to something like this:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.1.0'
```

also add `implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'` in your dependencies.